# UPDATE table if column exists

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I have two similar but not same tables. `res_partner` from Odoo. One table is from 10 version and another from 7. So columns differs a bit.

I need to update fields of first table using second table. Problem is that I don't know if column exists in 1 table or not. So question is how can update only those fields that exists in both tables?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question plus an example on what exactly you want to update. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

you can create `Reference` field in Odoo. Reference fields are like pointers to the field on different table so when related model field is updated field on given table it will auto update.

Bests